# Is there any possibility to get a notification when a certain file/ directory is deleted in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, hadoop2, webhdfs

I want to get a notification when a certain file/ directory has been deleted in HDFS. It would also be possible to generate a kind of log file with timestamp, affected file/ directory and so on. I need this due to traceability requirements.

Is there any script, software et cetera to cover this kind of task?

Comment: You could probably use something like Nagios to monitor the namenode log files.

Comment: Do you know where the namenode log files are located?

Comment: Depends on your Hadoop distribution. According to this blog article http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/09/apache-hadoop-log-files-where-to-find-them-in-cdh-and-what-info-they-contain/ at least in a Cloudera dist it should be in /var/log/hadoop/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-...

Comment: OK, thank you. But I think there must be an existing software for auditing the HDFS access log files, or?

Answer (score 0):

Use HdfsAdmin.[getInotifyEventStream](https://blog.woopi.org/wordpress/files/hadoop-2.6.0-javadoc/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/client/HdfsAdmin.html#getInotifyEventStream(long))(...) to open an DFSInotifyEventInputStream. Monitor the events in the stream for an event of type Event.[UnlinkEvent](https://blog.woopi.org/wordpress/files/hadoop-2.6.0-javadoc/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/inotify/Event.UnlinkEvent.html).